# How to show different pages for www and non-www versions

Tags: subdomain, no-www

A simple (probably stupid) question: is it possible to show different pages for `www` and `non-www` versions of a website?

I mean for example, `www.example.com` will show the content in `/mainfolder` and `domain.com` will show the content in `/secondfolder`.

I **don't want to redirect**, like if the user goes to `www.domain.com` he will be redirected to `domain.com/www` - I don't want that, I just wanna know how to show 2 different `index.html` files, one for the `www` version of the website and one for the version without `www`.

Or if possible, how can I create the `www` subdomain in cPanel (as it won't let me) - any way to override this?

#### UPDATE

I tried this *.htaccess* edit and it worked partially:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.site.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/folder/ [P]
```

It now shows the contents of `site.com/folder` when users access `www.site.com`
however it doesn't load the CSS of the page - any way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is definitely possible. But please note that, by convention, `www.domain.com` is just an alias for `domain.com`. So, what you describe is not at all standard and violates most users' expectations. It also runs at least some risk of search engine penalties. So, in my opinion, it is not a good idea, but yes, it's possible.

Exactly how you do it depends on the server and/or scripting technology. For example, you could do it with Apache, which would look like this (in a `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/whatever/?
RewriteRule . /whatever
```

This would send all requests for `www.domain.com` to `/whatever`, but would not affect requests on `domain.com`. This is probably overly simplistic for what you want, but you haven't provided a lot of detail.

You can do the same thing in a scripting language like Python or PHP, but how you do it depends on what exactly you want to do.

Also, the reason you can't create a `www` subdomain in cPanel is that it creates it automatically.

(*Edited: forgot to add the second RewriteCond to avoid a loop.*)

Comment: well, if i use that htaccess redirect, if the user goes to www.site.com > the address in the browser will then change to www.site.com/whatever or site.com/whatever - i don't want that. what i want is if the user goes to www.site.com he will be shown a page and the address in the browser will still be www.site.com; and if the user goes to site.com he will be shown a different page and the address in the browse will still be site.com; also is there a way to bypass cpanel and create www as a subdomain?

Comment: @user3288194: The code that Ed posted is not an "external redirect", it is an "internal rewrite" - the URL in the address bar will not change in this instance.

Comment: already tried that code but for some reason it redirects to site.com (the url in the address bar changes) and it does not load the content from the /whatever folder...

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1
```